# How do you pronounce $\mathbb{R}^2, \dots, \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-spaces, pronunciation

I've been starting some vector calculus and I keep pronouncing it "R squared" in my head, which is clearly wrong. What is a better way to pronounce it, so that I can state things like $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ out loud?

Comment: R-2, R-3, ..., R-n (so read it as if there were no superscript there).

Comment: Completely disjoint comment: You probably want $\to$ instead of $\mapsto$.

Comment: I say "R n", since in italian we say "Erre enne".

Comment: @fuglede thanks, changed it.

Comment: Would you just pronounce all of those as "ar?"

Comment: /ar-too/, ..., /ar-en/

Comment: Yes, as in "ar-two, ar-three,..., ar-enn"

Comment: "arr-two" or "arr-squared" are both fine

Comment: You can also call $\mathbb{R}^n$ "$n$-dimensional Euclidean space" if you want a phrase that sounds more noun-like.

Comment: AFAIK full name of this set is “real *n*-coordinate space”.

@Michael Joyce: depends on whether Euclidean structure is employed. This (perennial) confusion between “coordinate” and “Euclidean” spaces sometimes results in ridiculous misconceptions [and neologisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Euclidean_subspace) (BTW, this one created by one of math.SE’s regulars when he was young). When you assume E(*n*) or O(*n*) action, it is correct to think of the space as of Euclidean. When the symmetry is unlike it, or no symmetry at all, it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, "$\mathbb{R}$-squared" is fine.

To see this, imagine you have a set $X$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ elements. How many elements does $X^2$ have? You guessed it, it has $n^2$ elements.